# Recommend solution for NFS v3 server on windows?

Tags: windows, nfs

I am looking for a solution to get an NFS v3 server up and running on windows.  I have tried using cygwin however their release of the NFS server is v2 which has a limit of 2GB files.

I am trying to get the partion from the unix drive (using ufsdump) on partitions larger than 2GB.  To my knowledge this command can not span files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give MS Windows [Services for Unix](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463212.aspx) a try. It supports Ver 3.

Comment: Great stuff, didn't know about those! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`ufsdump` by itself cannot span files, however you can use the split command to get around your limitation by splitting the stream into 1GB chunks:

```
ufsdump /filesystem | split -b1G /nfsmount/filesystem.dump.
```